# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, nodes, node-modules

Can someone please suggest how to turn off the certificate verification to false in nodejs.
I tried npm config set strict-ssl false but didn't work in my case.
please suggest any other possible option.

Comment: which operation that caused this issue? are you making an http request from your nodejs app?

Comment: I figured out this issue is due to network restrictions to upload an image into google cloud. But trying the alternatives to nullify the  restrictions but didn't work.process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'
npm config –global http.ssslverify false
npm config edit, strict-ssl=false
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
set NODE_ssl_UNAUTHORIZED=0
client.tls_insecure_set(True)
npm config strict-ssl false
set require_tls_cert false